# RSpec - accessing array methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm new to testing and struggling with some of the concepts. I understand the idea is to test things in isolation through mocks and stubs, however am struggling with the following:

```
class Circle
  has_many :jobs

  def accepted
    jobs.where('sitter_id > 0')
  end
end

class Job
  belongs_to :circle
end
```

And my RSpec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Circle, type: :model, focus: true do

  let (:circle_1) { FactoryGirl.create(:circle, title: 'London',
                                                location: 'London',
                                                administrator_id: 1) }

  let (:job_1) { FactoryGirl.create(:job, start_time: "2016-11-14 20:00:00",
                                          end_time: "2016-11-14 23:00:00",
                                          tokens_offered: 6,
                                          requester_id: 1,
                                          circle_id: 1,
                                          sitter_id: 5,
                                          actual_start_time: "2016-11-14 20:00:00",
                                          actual_end_time: "2016-11-14 23:30:00",
                                          tokens_paid: 7) }

  before do
    circle_1.stub(:jobs).and_return([job_1])
  end

  describe 'instance methods' do
    context 'accepted' do 
      it 'should return jobs with a sitter' do 
        expect(circle_1.accepted).to include(job_1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This results in:

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `where' for #<Array:0x007feb4ae72858>
```

Would I then stub the behaviour of the where method on the array? What I'm confused by is surely that's exactly what I'm testing, and by stubbing it I'm basically telling the test what the code does rather than testing the code itself?

If someone could explain if I'm understanding this wrong, and either way how I can either rewrite the test or get it to pass, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `circle_id: circle_1.id` - and no need to stub the `jobs`

Comment: The job is being returned when calling circle_1.jobs, it's just RSpec doesn't know how to call 'where' on the array from what I can see

Comment: because you stub it as array, do what i suggested ;)

Comment: I come here to ask for help and then argue when it's given :D


You were absolutely right, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you stubbed AR collection to an array object, which of course does not have a `where` method.

You want to establish the association on the factory level. You can achieve it with

```
circle_id: circle_1.id # in job_1
```

Having this you won't have to stub the collection of jobs and your test will work as expected.

Comment: I stubbed the array as the associations weren't setting - however as you explained that returns a different object from circle.jobs. Now that ID's are being set properly everything is passing - thanks for the help.

Comment: @Mark make sure to accept the answer (checkmark near the answer score) if that solved the issue.